# Hide table td on resize

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to hide some `table td` when I resize window or screen size is small.
I tried CSS `media queries`

```
th:nth-last-child(-n+7) {display:none}
td:nth-last-child(-n+7) {display:none}
th:last-child {display:none}
td:last-child {display:none}
```

It works but CSS cannot count td, so if a table has only three `td` then above code hide all three `td`.
Please help me achieve this using jQuery :
hide `td`  on resize or screen size is small,

1. if screen width is 768px then show only six `td` and hide other from
   right side
2. if screen width is 480px then show only four `td`and hide other from
       right side
3. if screen width is 320px then show only three `td`and hide other
       from right side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:last-child` and `max-width` media queries instead.

`td:nth-child(n+7)` will only affect cells starting with the seventh cell in a row, `td:nth-child(n+5)` will only affect cells starting with the fifth cell in a row, and so on.

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
    td:nth-child(n+7),th:nth-child(n+7) {display:none}
}
@media (max-width:480px) {
    td:nth-child(n+5),th:nth-child(n+5) {display:none}
}
@media (max-width:320px) {
    td:nth-child(n+4),th:nth-child(n+4) {display:none}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/GsxPK/

Comment: lol I am so dumb, missed this simple step. Thanks @Blazemonger